# VS2013 and Git: pull fails to merge

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

We are trying to use Git (bitbucket) with VS and the build in provider. But the pull is constantly failing, stating that there are existing changes to the Web.config file. But Web.config is not even listed as a changed file (nor has it changed). If I use SourceTree or the command line:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
```

seems to work fine. (I stole the command line from source tree).

*EDIT*:
Sorry, I should have mentioned, that I am a git newb. I assume .gitattributes is looked for in **%USERPROFILE%/.gitattributes**. I don't seem to have one.

My **%USERPROFILE%/.gitattributes** looks like this:

```
    [user]
    email = xxxx
    name = xxxx

[core]
    excludesfile = E:\\UserFiles\\sheam\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt

[gui]
    recentrepo = E:/Projects/FieldCapBase

[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

**git config core.autocrlf** gives *input*, in the root folder.

Wondering if adding the autocrlf and quotepath settings to my global gitconfig would make a pull in VS behave like in source tree?

Comment: Tell us more about your `.gitattributes` and your `core.autocrlf` settings and the line endings that file actually has?

Comment: My manual page for `gitattributes` seems to indicate that `%USERPROFILE%/git/attributes` or `%USERPROFILE%/.config/git/attributes` would be the proper locations, instead of `%USERPROFILE%/.gitattributes`. However, it's possible that was tweaked for whatever build of `git` you're using - I would suggest reviewing `git help gitattributes` to confirm that...

Comment: `.gitattributes` files can also be stored in the repository folder (usually in the root). You can just go to the command prompt, change directory to your source folder and type `git config core.autocrlf` to see the value @EdwardThomson was asking for

Comment: Thanks. Updated question with the info.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some really strange things like this happen when using git within Visual Studio 2013, it seems to be able to go strangely out of sync with the actual state of git when certain operations are performed, one example is if you add an existing file from another project VS will sometimes totally ignore or falsely report the state of the file and will refuse to add the file to your staging area, where the command line shows the proper state and adds the file as expected.

I could be incorrect and missing something as I'm something of a git noob too but I'm pretty sure this is a bug with the provider.

The only solution I have found is to use the command line for my git operations and just use VS for viewing diffs and exploring the repo.

Not so much a solution as a workaround but git is such a joy to use at the command line it's worth learning.

Comment: Please give us a shout if you think that the git provider is behaving incorrectly, we're happy to investigate with you.

Comment: I will have a play around and see if I can reproduce the problem, interestingly once I had updated the staging area from the command line VS seemed to catch up and then everything functioned correctly.

Comment: Ed - what exactly do you want? I can do a video of it happening. The provider gives no feedback on what the problem is, other that libgit produced an error. Going into Source Tree or command line and doing the pull works fine.